How to use clang AST writer to change a callExpr's argument name?
Given code such as:
auto r = func(std::move(a));

I'm trying to use the writer to add a new if block while introducing a new variable. The expected new code would be:
if (condition) {
    r = func(std::move(newA));
} else {
    r = func(std::move(a));
}

I'm able to add the if block, but I haven't found a way to copy the original expression and change the argument name in the new if block.
Current code to add if block:
void addGaterBlock(
    const clang::SourceManager* sm,
    Writer* writer,
    const VarDecl* call) {

  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << "if (condition) {\n";
  writer->insertBefore(call, ss.str());
  auto loc = clang::Lexer::findLocationAfterToken(
      call->getEndLoc(), clang::tok::semi, *sm, clang::LangOptions(), false);
  writer->insertAt(loc, "\n}");
}

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Could you please provide a minimal working example? (add necessary include files, compilation line, main ...)
